# No Outlook emails in my Windows Phone

Tags: sync, email, outlook

I have a Nokia Lumia 520. I have configured Outlook with the settings received from my company. But I'm not able to see old mails in it. I also downloaded Outlook Hotmail connector, but I see only new emails. And it shows only 2 emails. What is the solution?

Answer (score 4):

Can you change the settings yourself. If so, you can follow this guide: [**How to Set Up and Manage Email Sync on Windows Phone 8**](http://www.guidingtech.com/20140/set-up-manage-email-sync-windows-phone-8/). In the settings you cannot only set the interval at which the account should be synced (every 30 or 60 minutes for example) but also from which moment on the mail should be retrieved. For example: from the past 3 or 7 days, last month or all e-mails. Hope this helps!

### Update:

Here are the steps to follow to change the sync settings:

1. navigate to `settings` -> `email + account`
2. select the one you want to manage
3. choose the frequency at which your phone should attempt to fetch email messages from your account
4. choose the timespan for which messages should be downloaded.

Step 4 is the one where you select how far back in time messages should be fetched.

Comment: Hi Abbas, it would be advisable to post the actual steps here as opposed to just linking to the steps. If the link was to die, your answer would  be of no use in its current state

Comment: @karancan You're right, I should have done this directly. But why the downvote? My answer is not irrelevant in any way. If it's not the solution, further info should be provided by the OP.

Comment: That's not for me to say because it wasn't my down vote

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Go in to your Outlook app
2. Tap the `...` at the bottom right of the screen
3. Choose `settings`
4. Choose `sync settings`
5. For the option labelled `Download email from`, choose the